# Matching tuple elements with "as" pattern

Tags: f#

I'd like to convert tuple of two elements having the same type to a list. Code looks simple as this:

```
let toList (tuple: 'a * 'a): 'a list =
    match tuple with
    | (_ as fst, _ as snd) -> [fst; snd]
```

But somehow type of `snd` is `'a * 'a`, so it seems like instead of binding second element of tuple to a variable the whole tuple is bound instead. Is it a bug in compiler or am I missing sth?

Actual code is more complicated, so the idea is not to rewrite the piece provided, but to understand what is wrong with the `as` usage here. I'd expect that `as` should go after the tuple to bound it as a whole, like this `| (_ as fst, _ as snd) as tuple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For practical purposes @nilekirk's answer is better: you don't need `as` in this particular case at all.

But if you're wondering why `snd` has this type for learning purposes, here's an explanation.

---

Your pattern is compiled like this:

```
| ((_ as fst, _) as snd) ->
```

That is, tupling binds stronger than pattern aliasing.

If you want each `as` to apply to a single element of the tuple, you need to explicitly tell the compiler how to parenthesize them:

```
| ((_ as fst), (_ as snd)) ->
```

And incidentally, in F# tuples don't have to be in parens, so the outer parens are not necessary:

```
| (_ as fst), (_ as snd) ->
```

Comment: As I mentioned rewriting code to some other form is not what I need, as in reality It's more complicated: identifier pattern is used, and I need to check the DU type and to extract tuple element at the same time. Accepting yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntactic form of the "as" pattern is

> *pat* as *ident*

This defines *ident* to be equal to the pattern input and matches the pattern input
against *pat*.

For your code this means

```
let toList (tuple: 'a * 'a): 'a list =
    match tuple with
    | (fst, snd) -> [fst; snd]
```

where `(fst, snd)` is a tuple-pattern.

See [F# language spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) section 7.3 for full details of the "as" pattern.